# Android - facebook login error

Tags: android, facebook

Logcat

[image]

I have this code

```
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext()); 
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_social);

    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    info = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.info);
    loginButton = (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.login_button);

    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            info.setText(
                    "User ID: "
                    + loginResult.getAccessToken().getUserId() 
                    + "\n" +
                    "Auth Token: "
                    + loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken()
                );
        }
    });
}
```

App crash when i run it. I don't know why this crash, please help me! Thanks

Comment: Try cleaning and rebuilding your project

Comment: Can you show the manifest? Are you sure that you included this in the manifest?<activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
          android:configChanges=
                 "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
          android:label="@string/app_name" />